# Calculate balance by subtracting amount from previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get remaining amount by subtracting from previous record remaining amount my query is:

```
select date, EmployNumber
  , (select count(*) from List) as Total
  , Qty
  , ((select count(*) from List) - 1) as Remaining
from Employ
```

I am getting data in this way:

```
Date     EmployNumber  Total    Qty  Remaining  
1-2-20    123           64       1      63
1-2-20    124           64       1      63
1-2-20    125           64       1      63
```

I want the result in this way:

```
Date     EmployNumber  Total    Qty  Remaining  
1-2-20    123           64       1      63
1-2-20    124           64       1      62
1-2-20    125           64       1      61
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Dale K yes you are right i was trying to do so. Best part is that you noticed it :) by the way thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your `Qty` might not always be 1, the following will decrease the total by the `Qty` amount.

```
declare @Employ table ([Date] date, EmployNumber int, Qty int);
declare @List table (id int);

insert into @Employ ([Date], EmployNumber, Qty)
values ('01-02-2020', 123, 1), ('01-02-2020', 124, 2), ('01-02-2020', 125, 3);

insert into @List (id)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);

select E.*, L.Total
  -- Range is the default, but easier to understand when explicit
  , L.Total - sum(Qty) over (order by EmployNumber asc range between unbounded preceding and current row) Remaining
from @Employ E
cross apply (select count(*) Total from @List) L;
```

Which returns (using my test data):

| Date | EmployNumber | Qty | Total | Remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | 123 | 1 | 10 | 9 |
| 2020-01-02 | 124 | 2 | 10 | 7 |
| 2020-01-02 | 125 | 3 | 10 | 4 |

Comment: Nice one, just a point might be worth partitioning it by Employee and ordering by date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
Select t.*, total - row_number() over (order by employnumber) as remaining
From (your_query) t
```